# Filtering for spefic colums in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, optimization, data-structures

I try to make a custom data structure for my needs. I want to log simulation variables with a bit of extra information. I want to create an preallocated 2d numpy array and fill out values every timestep. And i want some convienence features such as that variables can be menmber of a group, this would be usefull for making an energy balance.

My problem is that my get_group function is way too slow. Do I need a dict with group names as keys and colum indices as a list or is there a diffrent way?

I would be also thankful for any other suggestion to improve the class.

```py
class State:

    def __init__(self,time_step_size):
        self.mapping = dict()
        self.group = dict()
        self.description = dict()
        sec_in_year = 31536000
        time = np.linspace(0, sec_in_year, int(np.floor(sec_in_year / time_step_size)))
        self.data = np.empty([len(time),1],dtype=float)
        self.data[:,0] = time
        self.mapping['time'] = 0
        self.group['time'] = None
        self.description['time']="Simulation time in sec"
        self.current_timestep = 0

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[:,self.mapping[key]]

    def get_group(self, group_name):
        vars=[k for k, v in self.group.items() if v == group_name]
        cols=[self.mapping[k] for k in vars]
        return self.data[:,cols]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[:,self.mapping[key]]=value

    def add_var(self, var_name, group, description):
        if var_name in self.mapping or var_name in self.group or var_name in self.description:
            raise Exception("Tried to add a variable to the state, that already exists")

        to_append=np.empty([len(self.data),1])
        to_append[:]=np.nan
        self.data=np.append(self.data,to_append,axis=1)

        self.mapping[var_name]=self.data.shape[1]-1
        self.group[var_name]= group
        self.description[var_name] = description
```

Comment: @qouify Thanks for the fast reply. I canged the like to vars={k for k, v in self.group.items() if v == group_name} but it did not result in any speed up

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do and why your code is slow, it is because `get_group` is run many times, or maybe you have thousands of cols. You need to provide small reproducible example: add some sample data, remove not necessary for us code lines.